# How do I know when RiotWatcher encounters a 429 error?

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-429, riot-games-api

I use RiotWatcher to access the riot API with python. Since I do a lot of queries with a development key, I try to watch out for 429 errors indicating an overrun of the allowed query rate.

In doing some testing, it seems that RiotWatcher includes an automatic RetryAfter, which is consistent with the [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/riot-watcher/downloads/pdf/latest/). If the limit is exceeded, it pauses and restarts as soon as a query is available.

I tried the following example given in the documentation, but it does not work as I imagined.

```
try:
        response = watcher.summoner.by_name(region, 'Poco')
    except ApiError as err:
        if err.response.status_code == 429:
            print('We should retry in {} seconds.'.format(err.headers['Retry-After']))
            print('this retry-after is handled by default by the RiotWatcher library')
            print('future requests wait until the retry-after time passes')
        elif err.response.status_code == 404:
            print('Summoner with that ridiculous name not found.')
        else:
            raise
```

On error 429, the request pauses and continues after the time has elapsed, but I never get the error message.

Do you know if it is possible to know when the watcher pauses due to a 429 error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring the Riot Watcher package code, in particular the BasicRateLimiter.py file, I found the following code, line 49:

```
LOG.debug(
  "waiting for %s seconds due to %s limit...",
  to_wait.total_seconds(),
  wait_until[1],
         )
```

So to get the information about the pause to limit requests, and the remaining time, just look at the DEBUG messages in the log.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://riot-watcher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/riotwatcher/Riot/index.html when you create the watcher instance, you can specify the rate limiter to be used. It defaults to `Handlers.RateLimit.BasicRateLimiter` so you should probably set it to your own subclass, or it may also work with None. The default rate limiter will be intercepting the 429 errors and doing the retries without you ever seeing the errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been looking through this documentation to see what argument I could fill in as a query limiter, but I haven't found one that fits what I'm looking for.

I don't want to change the limit which looks perfectly optimized, but just make the break more verbose. Do you think I should create a Handler myself by modifying the BasicRateLimiter to be more verbose (which I think is beyond my capabilities...)?